# Window not responding while using sockets SFML

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, udp, sfml

I am doing some simple SFML game, and I want to have network communication using udp Sockets. But the problem is that window is blocked and not responding if I try to update position of circle using coordinates that socket receives. Here is the code below. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int posX=100,posY=220,x=5;
sf::UdpSocket receiver;
sf::SocketSelector selector;

void changePosition ();
void defineWindow(sf::RenderWindow &window);
void drawCircle(sf::CircleShape &circle, sf::RenderWindow &window);

int main ()
{
  receiver.bind(15000);
  selector.add(receiver);

  sf::RenderWindow window (sf::VideoMode(800,600), "Krugovi");

  defineWindow (window);

  return 0;
}

void changePosition ()
{
  if (x>0 && posX+x>685) {
    posX=685;
    x=-x;
  }
  else if (x<0 && posX+x<15) {
    posX=15;
    x=-x;
  }
  else
    posX=posX+x;
}

void defineWindow(sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
  sf::CircleShape circle(50);
  sf::Event event;
  sf::Clock clock;

  while (window.isOpen()) {
    while(window.pollEvent(event)) {
      if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
        if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
          window.close();
      }
      if (event.type==sf::Event::Closed)
        window.close();
    }

    window.clear(sf::Color::White);

    char msg[5];
    size_t received;
    sf::IpAddress ip;
    unsigned short port;

    std::string string;

    if (selector.wait()) {
       if(receiver.receive(msg,sizeof(msg),received,ip,port)==sf::UdpSocket::Done) {
        posX=atoi(msg);
      }
    }

    drawCircle(circle,window);

    window.display();
  }
}

void drawCircle(sf::CircleShape &circle, sf::RenderWindow &window)
{
  circle.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
  circle.setOutlineThickness(15);
  circle.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Red);
  circle.setPosition(posX,posY);
  window.draw(circle);
}
```

Comment: You will need to enable non-blocking sockets using the proper flag. I'm not familiar with SFML but somewhere in the documentation you should find the way to enable the option. You will then need to modify your code to continue running without data received on the network.

Answer (score 2):

`sf::SocketSelector::wait()` without any parameters will wait forever until something is received on one of it's sockets, so you won't be responding to events in your window.

If you pass it a time to wait, for example `sf::milliseconds(5)` then you can continue to poll for events

[Relevent docs here](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php#a9cfda5475f17925e65889394d70af702)